# Export/Import of Azure ServiceBus Topic Subscriptions

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Is it possible to restore all subscriptions of an Azure ServiceBus topic as a backup copy and to import them into another ServiceBus namespace? We have a ServiceBus namespace with 1000 topic subscriptions and would like to back them up in the event that the ServiceBus namespace is accidentally deleted, for example.

Update: I found out that I can export the template of the ServiceBus Namespace Resource which includes the subscriptions. How can I export the template automatically and periodically?

Comment: I think that you can try it using powershell, you have to create and script and use the Example 2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/export-azresourcegroup?view=azps-5.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely various ways to achieve it. A simple export could be done from the portal by navigating to the source namespace and under the `Automation` section choosing `Export template.`

[image: menu]

That will generate an ARM template that can be tweaked and used to generate another Azure Service Bus namespace with all the entities and their settings.

The same mechanism can be used later to upload your ARM template and parameters file and rebuild/create a namespace.

[image]

Alternatively, you could use Azure PowerShell or AZ CLI to deploy.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I was hoping that Azure would offer a configuration to regularly and automatically export the template. Apparently this is not possible, so you always have to export the template manually or create a service yourself that performs the export via script.

Comment: I've not tried it but maybe [Azure Automation runbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types) could be helpful with the automation.